# SVG values submit to database...from form

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to make a svg tooth that is clickable and send the clicked tooth value to my database.. how to do it/?

i tried to add css to my svg but the hover is not working ..even if i target the class of the "path".

````
.toothdiv {
  background:linear-gradient(141deg, #0fb8ad 0%, #1fc8db 51%, #2cb5e8 75%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
a path:hover{
  fill:red;
}
```SVG
<svg class="toothdiv"



<!-- 1 -->
<a href="#" class="ako" xlink:title="3rd Molar" >
````

im expecting to add a hover effect when the mouse pointer is on top of the svg path.

Comment: CSS selectors cannot cross the shadow-DOM boundary

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is this: every tooth has an id and there is an input (type text in this example - *you can make them type `hidden`*) with a similar id. For example if the tooth id is `id="_3m"` there is an input whose's id is `id="input_3m"`. Also the tooth has a data-value attribute. When the user is clicking the tooth the value of the `data-value` appears as value of the input. I hope it helps.

```js
//the array of teeth
let teeth = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("circle"))
//for each tooth
teeth.forEach(c=>{
  //get the id of the tooth
  let theId = c.id;
  
  // get the vinculated input
  let theinput = document.querySelector("#input"+theId);
  //on click
  c.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    //add the class selected to the tooth
    c.setAttribute("class","selected")
    theinput.value = c.dataset.value
  })
  
  
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
.selected{fill:red}
```

```html
<svg> 
  <circle id="_3m" data-value ="3rd molar" cx="150" cy="75" r="7" />
  <circle id="_4m" data-value ="4rd molar" cx="165" cy="75" r="7" />
</svg>

<form action="http://foo.com" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="input_3m" />
  <input type="text" id="input_4m" />
  <button>Send the file</button>
</form>
```